# Accurate spending time solution

Tags: java, c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

Considering the following code snippets

```
class time implement Runnable{
 long t=0L;
 public void run(){
  try{while(true){Thread.sleep(1000);t++;/*show the time*/}}catch(Throwable t){}
 }
}
```

////

```
long long t=0L;
void* time(void* a){//pthread thread start
sleep(1);t++;//show the time
}
```

I read in some tutorial that in Java `Thread.sleep(1000)` is not exactly 1 second, and it might be more if the system is busy at the time, then OS switch to the thread late.
Questions:

Is this case true at all or no?
Is this scenario same for native (`C/C++`) codes?
What is the accurate way to count the seconds up in an application?

Comment: Even if you don't sleep and just poll `System.nanoTime()` you will see a lot of jitter up to milli-seconds on an otherwise quiet machine. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/micro-jitter-busy-waiting-and-binding.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have answered about the accuracy of timing. Unfortunately, there is no GUARANTEED way to sleep for X amount of time, and wake up at exactly X.00000 seconds (or milliseconds, nanoseconds, etc).

For displaying time in seconds, you can just lower the time you are waiting to, say, half a second. Then you won't have the time jump two seconds from time to time, because half a second isn't going to be extended to more than a second (unless the OS & system you are running on is absolutely overloaded and nothing gets to run when it should - in which case you should fix that problem [get a faster processor, more memory, or whatever it takes], not fiddle with the timing of your application). This works well for "relatively long periods of time", such as one second or 1/10th of a second. For higher precision, it won't really work, since we're now entering the "scheduling jitter" zone.

If you want very accurate timing, then you will probably need to use a Real-Time OS, or at least an OS that has "real time extensions enabled", which will allow the OS to be more strict about time (at the cost of "ease of use" from the programmer, and possibly also the OS being less efficient in it's handling of processes, because it "switches more often than it needs to", compared to a more "lazy" timing approach).

Note also that the "may take longer", in an idle system is mainly the "rounding up of the timer" (if the system tick happens every 10ms or 1ms, the timer is set to 1000ms + whatever is left of the current timer tick, so may be 1009.999ms, or 1000.75ms, for example). The other overhead, that come from scheduling and general OS overheads should be in the microseconds range if not nanoseconds on any modern system - after all, an OS can do quite a lot of work in a microsecond - a modern x86 CPU will execute 3 cycles per clock, and the clock runs around 0.3ns. That's 10 instructions per nanosecond [of course, cache-misses and such will worsen this dramatically]. If the OS has more than a few thousand instructions to go from one process to another (less still for threads), then there's something quite wrong. A few thousand instructions @ 10 instructions per nanonsecond = some hundreds of nanoseconds. Definitely less than a microsecond. Compare that to the 1ms or 10ms "jitter" of starting the timer just after the timer ticked off last time.

Naturally, if the CPU is busy running other tasks, this is different - then the time "left to run" on other processes will also influence the time taken to wake up a process.

Of course, in a heavily loaded memory system, the "just woken up" process may not be "ready to run", it could be swapped out to disk, for example. In which case, tens if not hundreds of milliseconds are needed to load it back from the disk.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Don Petersson, yes I used to use `system_current_time` instead, but I was wondering about another simpler solution. Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the two first questions: Yes it's true, and yes.

First there is the time between the timeout expires and the time when the OS notices it, then there the time for the OS to reschedule your process, and lastly there's the time from the process has been "woken up" until it is its turn to run. How long will all this take? There's no way of saying.

And as it's all done on the OS level, it doesn't really matter what language you program in.

As for a more accurate way? There is none. You can use more high-precision timers, but there is no way of avoiding the lag described above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it´s true that it is not accurate.
It´s the same for simple sleep-functions in C/C++ and pretty much everything else.
Depending on your system, there could be better functions accessible,
but:

> What is the accurate way

A really accurate way does not exist.
Unles you have some really expensive special computer with atomic clock included.
(and no usual OS too. And even then, we could argue what "accurate" means)

If busy waiting (high CPU load) is acceptable, look at nanoTime or native usleep,  HighPerformanceCounter or whatever is applicable for your system

Answer (score 1):

The sleep call tells the system to stop the thread execution for at least a time period specified as argument. The system will then resume thread execution when it has a chance (it actually depends on many factors, such as hardware, thread priorities, etc.). To more or less acurately measure the time you can store the time at the beginning of execution and then calculate the time delta each time it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

The sleep function is not accurate, but if the intent is to display the total amount of seconds then you should store the current time at the beginning and then display the time difference every now and then.

Answer (score 1):

This is true. Every `sleep` implementation in any language (`C` too) will fail to wait exactly 1 second. It has to deal with your OS scheduler, the sleep duration is juste a hint : `the minimum sleep duration` to be precise, but the actual difference depends on gigazillions of factors.

Trying to figure out the deviation is tricky if you want a very high resolution clock. In most cases, you'll have about 1~5 ms (roughly).

The thing is that the order of magnitude will be the same whatever the sleep duration. If you want something "accurate", you can divide your time application and wait for a longer period. For example, when you benchmark, you will prefer this type of implementation because the delta-time will increase, decreasing uncertainty :

```
// get t0
// process n times
// get t1    
// compute average time : (t1-t0)/n
```